# NextJS 13 App Router Script not rendering after first page load

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a project currently that is having an issue with a custom script in the NextJS 13 App Router. A certain page, in this case, the catalog page, loads a script when it is first visited that embeds an iframe to the page, when a user navigates away from the catalog page, and then back to the catalog page, the iFrame does not render in unless the page is completely refreshed.

Would the best solution be to force a reload whenever the user visits the catalog page, or is it possible for only the script to be loaded whenever the page is visited?

Comment: Could this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312954/js-how-to-reload-iframe-on-a-page-when-returning-back-from-a-link-in-the-ifram

Comment: have you read about nextjs caching and revalidatePath?